# Axios use duplicate params typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, axios

I'm working with an existing backend which I can not adjust anymore. I need to do a call which gets all messages. One of the params is type, this can be used to get all messages from a specific type. The backend developer had told me I had to use this multiple times looking like this:

> /api/message?type=test&type=test2

So i tried sending it as a array, which resulted in:

> /api/message?type[]=test&type[]=test2

Finding some information on SO made me use QS but this also doesn't give me the result I need

> api/message?type%5B0%5D=test&type%5B1%5D=test2

```
export const getMessages = () =>
  baseApi
    .get('/message', {
      params: {
        type: [
          'test',
          'test2'
        ]
      },
      paramsSerializer: (params) => {
        return qs.stringify(params)
      }
    })
    .then((r) => r.data as Message[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to Axios. The qs library is responsible for generating that string.  See its [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs):

> When arrays are stringified, by default they are given explicit
> indices:
>
> ```
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c', 'd'] });
> // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c&a[2]=d'
> ```
>
> You may override this by setting the indices option to false:
>
> ```
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c', 'd'] }, { indices: false });
> // 'a=b&a=c&a=d'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the append method. Like ([URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)):

```
const params = new URLSearchParams()
params.append("type","test")
params.append("type","test2")
```

Then, you set the params in the request just like you did:

```
export const getMessages = () =>
  baseApi
    .get('/message', {
      params: {
        params
      },
      paramsSerializer: (params) => {
        return qs.stringify(params)
      }
    })
    .then((r) => r.data as Message[])
```